# Any flutter shader example working with vertex uv/colors

Tags: flutter, shader

Can anyone point me to flutter shader example working with vertex uv/colors?
I want to use the Canvas.drawVertices() with their uv/color provided to a shader.

All flutter shaders I saw, rely on a single uSize set manually (but I need to render multiple areas):
void main() {
vec2 uv = FlutterFragCoord().xy / uSize;

Comment: can you include an image or more code?  You can render N areas as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.